# Wordpress website gets slow

Tags: wordpress, performance, web, loading

While adding new pages and information to pages of wordpress website, site became very slow. It takes 2 or 3 minutes to load for each page.

Anyone has idea, why this is hapening

Comment: To (technically) answer your question, I don't think anyone has an idea of why this is happening. You need to provide us more details about your site implementation and the pages you added to it to cause the problem.

Comment: i have posted if you think is right then check it not getting wordpress but you can every cms and frameworks

Answer (score 0):

I ahve give you one suggestion not for wordpress it works all the site load will be easily maintain

- Use a content delivery network (CDN)
- se an effective caching plugin
- Start with a solid framework/theme
- Optimize images (automatically)
- Optimize your homepage to load quickly

This isn’t one thing but really a few easy things that you can do to ensure that your homepage loads quickly, which probably is the most important part of your site because people will be landing there the most often.

- Show excerpts instead of full posts
- Remove unnecessary sharing widgets from the home page (include them
  only in posts)
- Remove inactive plugins and widgets that you don’t need
- Keep in minimal! Readers are here for content, not 8,000 widgets on
  the homepage
- Disable hotlinking and leeching of your content

**Place this code in your root .htaccess file:**

```
disable hotlinking of images with forbidden or custom image option
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?sparringmind.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?google.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?feeds2.feedburner.com/sparringmind [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ – [NC,F,L]
```

Add an expires header to static resources

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2592000
```

if possible Adjust Gravatar images

- Control the amount of post revisions stored
- Replace PHP with static HTML, when necessary

---